# Get value of innerText field in HTML element with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select HTML elements based on the condition of an email subject field. The problem I am having however is that I cannot seem to read the `innerText` or `innerHTML` elements of the selected field.

Initially I created an array of elements as below:

`mail = targets[0].getElementsByClassName('mailSubject');`

The screenshot below shows the `mail` object.

I tried just calling the name of the element such as `mail.innerText` but just got undefined.

How can I access this text value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the structure shared in screenshot, it seems you should get the value from `mail[0].innerText`

Answer (score 1):

As you shared in the screenshot, You are getting a [HTMLCollection (array-like object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

your code,

```
mail = targets[0].getElementsByClassName('mailSubject');
// so the getElementsByClassName() will return an HTMLCollection
```

So you can access the values of the required index,

ex:

```
mail[0].innerText
```